# Vue pass axios response to a different method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using this method to convert a currency value:

```
    converter (recipe_line) {
      axios.get('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=' + recipe_line.currency_buy + '&symbols=' + this.currentLocation.currency)
      .then(response => {
         let rate = response.data.rates[Object.keys(response.data.rates)[0]]
         return rate
      })
    },
```

This method gets called in another method :

```
recipeLineTotalConverted (recipe_line) {
  let pricebuy = this.converter(recipe_line)
}
```

In the first method, if i console.log(rate) the result is correct.

But in the second method, console.log(pricebuy) returns undefined.

How do I access the axios response in the second method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
converter (recipe_line) {
      axios.get('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=' + recipe_line.currency_buy + '&symbols=' + this.currentLocation.currency)
      .then(response => {
         let rate = response.data.rates[Object.keys(response.data.rates)[0]]
         return rate
      })
    },
```

Easiest approach would be to use `async/await` syntax to achieve what you're looking to do, this syntax lends toward a more synchronous feel to your code, making it (in my opinion) more readable.

```js
  async converter(recipe_line) {
    try {
      const response = await axiox.get(
        'https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=' +
          recipe_line.currency_buy +
          '&symbols=' +
          this.currentLocation.currency
      );

      return response.data.rates[Object.keys(response.data.rates)[0]];
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

It would look something like above, alternatively you could adjust it to look something like this:

```js
  converter(recipe_line) {
    axios
      .get(
        'https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=' +
          recipe_line.currency_buy +
          '&symbols=' +
          this.currentLocation.currency
      )
      .then((response) => {
        let rate = response.data.rates[Object.keys(response.data.rates)[0]];
        Promise.resolve(rate);
      })
      .catch((err) => Promise.reject(err));
  }
```

The problem is, you're not actually returning anything from inside that promise, it needs to either resolve, or be returned using another promise.

`return rate` doesn't resolve the promise (although it probably should), instead `Promise.resolve()` is used to achieve this.

So although the Promise does resolve, the return value isn't resolved as `.resolve()` isn't used.

Since ES6, the `async/await` syntax was added, giving us the ability to write code that's more synchronously styled, although still asynchronous as it's a wrapper around the older Promise syntax (`.then/.catch`).

- https://codeforgeek.com/asynchronous-programming-in-node-js/

Also, what's the use of `Object.keys(response.data.rates)`, couldn't this be referenced using the key name?

So for example, if the key is "rate1", you'd replace `response.data.rates['rate1']`.

I don't know your use-case, so that's just an after-thought.

Comment: Since I have .then I think the promise is resolved. You replaced async with .then but they both return the same result.

Comment: @Catmal I think I could explain that a little better, the promise needs to be `.resolve`(d) with the value you're trying to return (if using Promise syntax), using async/await the return option will work as it'll return a promise with the return value, or reject with an error if one is thrown. Hence, the try/catch block, instead of `.catch`. The first version resolves to `void` as nothing is `.resolve`(d). `Promise.resolve(returnValue)`.

Answer (score 0):

So two things wrong in your code.

1. You're not returning anything from your first method. You have to return the call to `axios.get(/* ... */)`
2. You're trying to get a value immediately out of an asynchronous operation. Even if you return the value from your first method, you'll just get `[object Promise]` instead of `undefined` as the value.

The most straightforward way to get around this would be to use `async/await`. However if you're trying to render this information in a view, you're going to need a data property one way or another as VueJS doesn't have a way to await asynchrounous operations directly inside a template.

I simplified your example a bit to work with an easier API but this is one way you can achieve this:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    url: ""
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.url = await this.getUrl();
  },
  methods: {
    getCat() {
      return axios
        .get("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search")
        .then((response) => {
          return response.data[0].url;
        });
    },
    async getUrl() {
      let catImage = await this.getCat();
      console.log(catImage); // you'll see this isn't undefined anymore
      return catImage;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">{{ url }}</div>
```

And since we're using `async/await` here anyway you can also drop the usage of a promise in your axios call and simplify to this:

```
    async getCat() {
      return (await axios("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search")).data[0].url;
    },
```

**Update**

You mentioned in the comments that you do need to render this data in your template. I just want to make it clear that what you're trying to do is basically this:

```js
<div>{{ getUrl() }}</div>
```

This is not possible in VueJS at this time. What will get rendered to the page is just `[object Promise]`. Because when you call `getUrl` (an asynchronous function) you'll first get a Promise. Vue won't update the rendered result of an asynchronous function. So when the Promise resolves (axios returns a result) you'll still see `[object Promise]` rendered on your page.

So that leaves you with two options. You can update the value of one of your `data` properties as a side effect of your asynchronous action, or alternatively you can bring in a library that gives you async computed properties:
https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed

Comment: Ok now I undertsand why the value is printed correctly in the first methos but not in the second. In the second it actually returns [object Promise]. The problem is that I'm getting the same result with async.await. About showing it in the template I just use {{recipeLineTotalConverted (recipe_line)}}. I'm going to keep trying..

Comment: Exactly so what I'm saying is you can't use that method in your template. You have to use a data property that gets updated after the promise resolves